# VIM scrolling lag in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, vim, virtualbox

I just installed ubuntu in my virtualbox.
I was trying to use vim and I noticed a weird behavior while scrolling:

The screen only updates after I release the keys, e.g., if I have a large file and press arrow down or "j", I don't see live updates. Instead the screen is only updated after I release the key.
Same happens with inserting new lines.

It works fine on my MacOS system.
Any pointers appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but `j` and `k` are not for scrolling, they are for moving the cursor. Scrolling is done with `<C-e>`/`<C-y>` (line-by-line), `<C-d>`/`<C-u>` (half screen-by-half screen), `<C-f>`/`<C-b>` (screen-by-screen).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being unclear. But on my host OS (MacOS) moving the cursors updates the screen buffer, whereas on the virtual machine the screen buffer only gets updated after I release the key.